# White page with loop loading in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a problem only in Firefox. When I click a button in my application in Firefox the page is white with infinite loading, it's in a loop.

I have done a debugger on my code with dev console and I found where the function breaks. Note that there are no errors in the console.

```js
function setSavedToSended() {
  console.log('sono nella funzione')

  if (projObjSave == undefined) {
    projObjSave = projObj;
  }

  var items = $("td [id-status]"); //the problem starts here
  for (var item in items) {
    var _this = parseInt($(items[item] /* here it breaks item*/ ).attr("id-status"));
    if (_this == 1) {
      var tempId = $(items[item]).attr("id")
      $("#" + tempId).attr("id-status", 2).addClass("sended");
      var currProj = tempId.split("_");
      var projIndex, taskIndex;

      for (var i = 0; i < projObj.length; i++) {
        if (currProj[0] == projObj[i].projectId) {
          projIndex = i;
        }
      }

      if (currProj.length == 3) {
        if (currProj[1] == "ORD") {
        projObjSave[projIndex].timeTrackingProjectList.timeTrackingOrdinario[currProj[2]]["idStatus"] = 2;
        } else {
        projObjSave[projIndex].timeTrackingProjectList.timeTrackingStraordinario[currProj[2]]["idStatus"] = 2;
        }
      } else {
        for (var index = 0; index < projObj[projIndex].taskList.length; index++) {
          if (currProj[1] == projObj[projIndex].taskList[index].taskId) {
            taskIndex = index;
          }
        }

        currProj[2] == "ORD" ? projObjSave[projIndex].taskList[taskIndex].timeTrackingTaskOrdinario[currProj[3]]["idStatus"] = 2 : projObjSave[projIndex].taskList[taskIndex].timeTrackingTaskStraordinario[currProj[3]]["idStatus"] = 2;
      }
    } else console.log('nothing done')
  }
  saveSendProject(2)
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest the use of [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over a jQuery collection. Also, it is not clear to me what are you trying to do with the line `$(items[item * ]).attr("id-status")`. What is that `*` trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to select a item and take attribute and after using parseint for convert it

Comment: it's items[item]

Comment: And when you say that the statement `$(items[item]).attr("id-status")` breaks, what do you mean by that? What do you have in `items`?

Comment: Solved using $(item).attr("id")